# grep first n lines only

Tags: regex, bash, shell, grep

I'm facing a problem greping the right date within a letter as a document.
Reason is to grep the date of document creation and not any further date within the text.

Usaly the dokument hold information about the company, my address, customer number, bill number....
and the date by when it was created.

Mayby a greeting and/or text maybe within dates again.

Often the date at begin of the document has different look as following.

3. December 1999 instead of 3.12.1999 as example.

If I grep the date in case of pattern

```
'(([0-9][0-9]{,1}\.)\s+('Januar'|'Februar'|'März'|'April'|'Mai'|'Juni'|'Juli'|'August'|'September'|'Oktober'|'November'|'Dezember')\s+([1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]{1,}))'
```

sometimes get the wrong date as creation date. Reason is the different writing of dates in the documents.
Example 1 is what I usualy get and it works fine as I search for the date (creation date) with correct pattern.
Example 2 is in problem as I get a date, but it's NOT creation date which would be the 1st date. I get instead another date matching the pattern out from the text.

Example 1
[image: Example 1]

Example 2
[image: Example 2]

I could use different pattern `'(([0-9][0-9]{,1}\.)([0-9][0-9]{,1}\.)([1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]{1,}))'` grepping the correct date in example 2 but then I would get same issue for example 1.

My idea was to search in first n lines only if pattern match take the date otherwise use different pattern.
I don't get the rule for `pdfgrep` using the first n lines only what would give me the possibility to use different pattern.

Has anybody an idea how to fix it?

Cheers, bdream

Comment: Have you considered using both patterns joined with `|` (or)? That would identify the first date occurrence matching either pattern, which seems to be what you want...

Comment: Replace images with its text and then add your desired output (no description) for that input to your question (no comment).

Comment: @bdream : If you find two dates within the first n lines you are restricting your search to, which one is the correct one? And how do you find a date if the writer decided to write it after the first n lines?  Maybe you should search the whole document for lines which look like "creation date line" (maybe many spaces in front of the date?) and take the first from these, no matter which line it is in. BTW, some people write the date at the end of the document, near the final greetings.

Comment: @hmm you are right - thanks
I can use `pdfgrep -o --max-count 1 '(([0-9][0-9]{,1}\.)([0-9][0-9]{,1}\.)([1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]{1,}))|('Datum:')\s+(([0-9][0-9]{,1}\.)([0-9][0-9]{,1}\.)([1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]{1,}))|(([0-9][0-9]{,1}\.)\s+('Januar'|'Februar'|'März'|'April'|'Mai'|'Juni'|'Juli'|'August'|'September'|'Oktober'|'November'|'Dezember')\s+([1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]{1,}))'  *.pdf
` figuring out the rigt date.

Have to think how to switch in different programm part on what kind of date were found.

Comment: @user1934428 you are right over all, but in my case I have a couple of documents and all have the date I like to use within the first 1/3 of first page.

Answer (score 3):

With GNU grep:

`-m NUM`: Stop  reading  a  file  after  NUM  matching  lines.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to [GNU `grep`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/) learn to use [GNU gawk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/), specifically designed for such tasks.

Consider also learning [python](https://python.org/) or [GNU guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/) (then read [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/index.html)).

Comment: Totaly right! Learning python is more than on my list.
Next part will be to transfer script into python.